# validate some specific fields in asp.net mvc 5 (vb)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form and I want to validate some fields only.
I used to disable some field validation using data-val="false".
It works ok in client side. But serverside it doesn't.

Here is my code

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
         <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(model) model.Sex, "M") Male
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
          <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(model) model.Sex, "F") Female
          </label>
      </div>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Sex, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-12 ">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.DateOfJoin, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "col-lg-4 control-label"})
    <div class="col-lg-8">
       @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.DateOfJoin, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control datefield", .data_val = False}})
       @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.DateOfJoin, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})*@
     </div>
  </div>
```

My model is

```
<MetadataType(GetType(EmployeeMasterMetaData))> _
Partial Public Class EmployeeMaster
  Public Overridable Property DepartmentMaster As DepartmentMaster
  Public Overridable Property DesignationMaster As DesignationMaster
End Class
Public Class EmployeeMasterMetaData

 <Required(ErrorMessage:="Sex is required")>
 Public Property Sex As String

 <Display(Name:="Date Of Join")>
 Public Property DateOfJoin As Date
End Class
```

I don't want to validate DateOfJoin field and empty values for it, can be save.
How can be done this?

Comment: Show you model. If you want to allow the `DateOfJoin` property to be `null`, then make the property nullable.

Comment: I have added model class

Comment: You need to make `DateOfJoin` nullable. Typeof `Date` cannot be null so if you post back an empty value, you will get a validation error.

Comment: Could you please an example? :)

Comment: What kind of example are you looking for? As Stephen says, just use a nullable date (i.e. `Date?`) instead of a regular `Date`.

Comment: Nope.. Still not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the date field to be nullable set your date like the following.

```
public DateTime? DateOfJoin { get; set; }
```

The Question mark after the datetime type sets the data as nullable. If Database first method is used, then allow the corresponding field to accept null value.